# what does m_gridMaps[0] means in icl-slam project of mrpt?

Tags: c++

I am confused with this:

```
CPosePDFPtr pestPose = ICP.Align(
                matchWith,                  // Map 1
                &sensedPoints,              // Map 2
                initialEstimatedRobotPose,  // a first gross estimation of map 2 relative to map 1.
                &runningTime,               // Running time
                &icpReturn                  // Returned information
                );
```

`sensedPoints` is a frame point data. I am not sure whether the `matchWith` is a frame point data before `sensedPoints` or a whole map data. If I want to align two adjacent frame point datas, how should I do it?

Comment: Where is `m_gridMaps[0]`, which is in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the reference docs of [`mrpt::maps::CMultiMetric`](http://reference.mrpt.org/devel/classmrpt_1_1maps_1_1_c_multi_metric_map.html).

As shown there, `m_gridMaps[i]` means the i'th occupancy gridmap in the set of metric maps.